# Kafka - Multiple producers writing to same topic and order of message is important

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, publish, publish-subscribe, producer-consumer

Let us say there are two Producers `P1 and P2`.
P1 makes attempt to write log L1 at time t1 to a partition PT however it gets written at t2 due to network latency.
P2 makes attempt to write log L2 at time t3 to a partition PT however it gets written at t4 due to network latency.

Let us say `t1<t3` however `t2>t4` so what will be the final order of L1 and L2 in the partition PT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if both producers are writing to the same Partition, the order of the messages will be the order of reception of those messages, regardless of when the Producer send the message.